# How to create a local alias for classes exported by internal modules in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Consider a file with typescript code(eg: uid.ts):

```
module uid {
  var id = 1;

  export class Uid {
    value: number;

    constructor() {
      this.value = id++;
    }
  }
}

module uid_generator {
  import Uid = uid.Uid;

  function generate(): Uid {
    return new Uid();
  }
}
```

When trying to compile this file(node.js, compiler version 0.9.0.1) I get the following errors:

```
$ tsc uid.ts
${HOME}/uid.ts(14,3): error TS2072: Module cannot be aliased to a non-module type.
${HOME}/uid.ts(17,16): error TS2083: Invalid 'new' expression.
```

From what I understood by reading the section 10.3 'Import Declarations' of the language specification, this should be the correct way to create an alias for class 'Uid' inside module 'uid_generator'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: By my reading of the spec that should work.  It could be a compiler bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've asked this question on [typescript discussion forum](http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/451555#post1073730) and it is indeed a compiler bug that was fixed in the current development branch.